# how to add a bullet every time a return key is pressed inside a react native textInput

Tags: react-native

Am trying to create a text input with multiline in a react native app, so that the user can add some notes. the issue am having is on inserting a bullet on the new line when a return key is pressed inside of that input box. Is there any technique to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This could help you.

```
import { useState } from "react";


export default function App() {
  const [text, setText] = useState();
  const change = (e) => {
    setText(e.target.value);
  };
  const checkEnter = (e) => {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      console.log(String.fromCharCode());
      setText(text + "•" + " ");
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <textarea onChange={change} onKeyUp={checkEnter} value={text} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this into your `TextInput` component. The only thing you need to evaluate is the last character typed. You could also use `onKeyPress` prop to check if it was a line break but it would overcomplicate, since you cannot prevent line breaks from your `onChangeText`

```
        onChangeText={(txt) => {
          if (txt.substr(-1) === '\n') {
            setTypedText(`${txt}*`);
          } else {
            setTypedText(txt);
          }
        }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer.

```
const [text, setText] = React.useState('');

const onChangeText = (newText: string) => {
    const bullet = '\u2022';
    const isLineBreak = newText.lastIndexOf('\n') === newText.length - 1;
    if (isLineBreak) {
      setText(newText + bullet);
    } else {
      setText(newText);
    }
};

...

<TextInput multiline value={text} onChangeText={onChangeText} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer. Hope this helps you

```
onChangeText={text => {
  if (textState.length > text.length) {
    setTextState(text)
    return
  }

  const newText = text
    .split('\n')
    .map(textLine =>
      textLine[0] === '\u2022'
        ? textLine
        : '\u2022 ' + textLine,
    )
    .join('\n')

  setTextState(newText)
}}
```